# how to create an arraylist of objects of a fixed size and pass on the remaining values to the next arraylist

Tags: java

I need to create Arraylists of size 1000 that are dynamically created when the user enters a number of values.Say if the user enters 2200 values,  2 ArrayLists of 1000 each ,and one Arraylist of 200 have to be created dynamically. How should i go about? I just know that i can use Arraylist of objects. Please help

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Can you post some code. what every you tried.?

Comment: Remeber to accept the correct answer if it was userful.

Answer (score 2):

Since you never did specify that you'd have to initialize the objects...you can use this.

```
public List<ArrayList<Object>> dynamicSizedLists(final int size) {
    List<ArrayList<Object>> retVal = new LinkedList<ArrayList<Object>>();
    final int MAX_SIZE = 1000;
    int iterations = size / MAX_SIZE;
    for(; iterations > 0; iterations--) {
        retVal.add(new ArrayList<Object>(MAX_SIZE));
    }
    retVal.add(new ArrayList<Object>(size % MAX_SIZE));

    return retVal;
}
```

You can observe in a debugger that these are partitioned properly via the `elementData` private field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayList's `size()` method to check if the size has reached 1000 and then add entries in another arraylist.

Comment: thank you..yes i can use..but how to create the arraylists dynamically using objects??

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Guavas](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) `Lists.partition` operation of split your list of all data into chunks of your desired size + one chunk of all the rest. Always worked for me. [Check the javadoc here if you're unsure](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29).

Comment: Thank you..but i need to create separate lists.

Comment: Well it returns a List of Lists, you could just retrieve them from it. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this (note I'm not using generics because you can't have generic arrays):

```
ArrayList entered = new ArrayList();
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number (enter a non-number to stop)\n>");
        entered.add(in.nextInt());
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e)
    {
        break;
    }
}
List[] lists = new List[entered.size() / 1000 + 1];
int currentElement = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < lists.length; ++i)
{
    lists[i] = entered.subList(currentElement, (currentElement + 1000 < entered.size()) ? currentElement + 1000 : entered.size());
    currentElement += 1000;
}
```

Comment: Where do you see arrays being mentioned?

Comment: can you tell me how to go about using arraylist of objects?

Comment: Sorry about that, you need typecast when getting or removing an element from the list. Fixed another mistake, needed to add 1000 to currentElement before proceeding to next iteration.