# How should i insert values into the dynamically created arraylists?

Tags: java

Makoto [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15354784/451518) the question i posted..This was his answer to my question of creating dynamical arraylists.

```
public List<ArrayList<Object>> dynamicSizedLists(final int size) {
    List<ArrayList<Object>> retVal = new LinkedList<ArrayList<Object>>();
    final int MAX_SIZE = 1000;
    int iterations = size / MAX_SIZE;
    for(; iterations > 0; iterations--) {
        retVal.add(new ArrayList<Object>(MAX_SIZE));
    }
    retVal.add(new ArrayList<Object>(size % MAX_SIZE));

    return retVal;
}
```

How should i insert values into the created arraylists??

Comment: what you have to insert??? From where you are getting the value??

Comment: You can get each list and then add values to that list.

Comment: Please elaborate your requirements

Comment: From the user input i have to get the values and insert them into the arraylists.

Comment: How should i get to each list when they do not have a name of their own coz' they have been generated dynamically??

Answer (score 0):

Get a list from the *list of lists*, and add an element:

```
List<ArrayList<Object>> lists = dynamicSizedLists(3);

lists.get(0).add("Hello World");
lists.get(1).add("Foo");
lists.get(1).add("Bar");

ArrayList<Object> list = lists.get(2);
list.add(new Integer(2));
System.out.println(lists);
```

BTW, it should be `List<List<Object>>` (or perhaps `<T> List<List<T>>`) in the implementation of `dynamicSizedLists`. Using collection classes instead of interfaces is bad style.

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
for(; iterations > 0; iterations--) 
{ 
    //create the array list first,
    ArrayList<Object> obj = new ArrayList<Object>(MAX_SIZE)
    //populate the contents of the above array list 
    obj.add(WhatEverThatIsToBeAdded);
    //finally add the above arraylist to your retVal list
    retVal.add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I think, You can get single arraylist from the list of Array list through get() and then you can add your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through retVal with foreach

```
for(ArrayList<Object> list : retval){
   list.add(object);
}
```

Or you can do it with simple for operator

```
for(int i = 0; i < retVal.size(); i++){
   retVal.get(i).add(object);
}
```